# Wrapper class to control styles?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can we use a wrapper class to control style in visualforce? I couldn't find any documentation. Could very well be a pipe dream, but worth asking!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by control style and maybe an example of type and usage of wrapper classes in another language/platform ?

Comment: @Sdry LaceySnr just illustrated with a terrific example. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of depends on what you mean.  I believe the answer is yes though.  I have an example of 1 way below.  There are several different ways to accomplish it.

**Controller**

```
//Wrapper class contained in some controller
public class MyWrapper
{
    public boolean isStyled{get; private set;}
    public Account accData{get; private set;}

    public MyWrapper(Account acc, boolean doStyling)
    {
        accData = acc;
        isStyled = doStyling;
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="SomePageUsingWrapperList">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wrap">
        <apex:column>
          <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
          <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.accData.name}" style="{!IF(wrap.isStyled, 'color:red', '')}" />
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Did you have to do anything special to get the '<' char to work?

Comment: use the code format button {} in the editor.

Comment: Ahhh thanks.  I've just been manually entering '<pre>' tags.

Comment: Alternatively, prefix every line you want to display in a code block with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a wrapper class? If not you can just set CSS classes on various tags. Most VF tags accept a `styleClass` parameter which allows you to specify CSS classes that should be applied to the final THML tag.

If you want to control the styling from Apex then wrapper classes can be useful. I have used wrapper classes that include some data and then a string variable, which itself contains names of CSS classes to apply. Using this with the `styleClass` tag lets you decide in apex which CSS classes should be applied to which items in the page.

### Wrapper Method

**Controller**

```
class wrapper
{
  public String cssClasses {get; set;
  public Contact c {get; set;}
}

public List<wrapper> contacts {get; set;}

// populate the list, add css classes etc. in your action methods / init
```

**Page**

```
<ul>
  <apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="c">
    <apex:outputText value="{!c.c.FirstName}" styleClass="{!c.cssClasses}">
  </apex:repeat>
</ul>
```

---

### Alternative - Dynamic Visualforce Binding

Now we have dynamic binding in VF you can keep your code cleaner by not using a wrapper class, and instead using a map, e.g.:

**Controller**

```
Map<Id, String> mapContactToCSS = new Map<Id, String>();

// snip

mapContactToCSS.Put(c.Id, 'highlight');
```

**Page**

```
<apex:outputText value="{!c.FirstName}" styleClass="{!mapContactToCSS[c.Id]}"/>
```

Comment: I was exploring all  possibilities :) Thanks. It's much clearer now.